# Sorting values in a HashMap

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have a `HashMap<Character, Integer>` and I'd like to place the values into a `PriorityQueue` in ascending order of the integers.  I'm having trouble thinking of a way to do this.  I have a `Node` class that can hold the values, so: `PriorityQueue<Node>`.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java

Comment: Use a `SortedMap` (for example, `TreeMap`) instead: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html

Comment: I looked at that thread before posting, but I am not trying to sort the map itself(which is complicated and pretty much impossible due to the nature of hashmaps), but select them in an ordered manner.

Comment: yuushi, I would use a treemap or linked hash map if I had a choice :(

Comment: is Node class created by you or u have edit/subclass access to the Node class?

Comment: It is my own class, it holds a character and an integer.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a `Map` in this case....

Write your own `Pair`/`Node` class that holds your `Character` and `Integer` and make this class implement `Comparable`.

You can read up on `Comparable` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

In your Node Class you will have to implement the `compareTo` method, somthing like this:

```
public int compareTo(Node o) {
    return this.idd - o.idd ;
}
```

Where id is the variable holding your integer.

Like this you can put them in a `SortedSet` like a `TreeSet` or the `PriorityQueue` you mention in your question

Comment: ok, implemented comparable and overrode compareTO so that it returns -1 for less than, 0 for equal numbers, and 1 if greater than.

Comment: OK, now just put the nodes in a sorted collection and see the magic happen.

Comment: ya I decided to put them all in the priority queue and then sort.  Collections.sort() does not seem to work with my priority queue though :(
ok, I re-read the doc on priorityQueue, looks like it automagically orders itself.

Comment: The priorityqueue will sort automaticly on insert...if it does not you made a mistake when implementing comparable... beware of generics

Answer (score 0):

Code example:

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> h = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
h.put('z',30);
h.put('e',10);
h.put('b',20);
h.put('c',20);
List<Map.Entry> a = new ArrayList<Map.Entry>(h.entrySet());
Collections.sort(a,
                 new Comparator() {
                     public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                         Map.Entry e1 = (Map.Entry) o1;
                         Map.Entry e2 = (Map.Entry) o2;
                         return ((Comparable) e1.getValue()).compareTo(e2.getValue());
                     }
                 });

for (Map.Entry e : a) {
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue());
}
```

Output (ordered by integer value as required by OP):

```
e 10
b 20
c 20
z 30
```